# mounting subdirectory with mount.cifs gives permission denied, but gvfs works

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mount, server-message-block, cifs

On a windows file share we have a user "drone" who is given read write permissions to ONLY access a subfolder "child": /SHARE/parent/child
But is not given read/write access to "parent" (however is allowed to list directories).

I want to access the subfolder "child" directly from an ubuntu minimal install (server) 14.04 LTS using the "drone" user. I prefer NOT to install gvfs and all its dependencies.

This works PERFECTLY (tested from my ubuntu 14.04 desktop machine):

```
$ gvfs-mount smb://drone@server.domain.org/SHARE/parent/child mount_folder
```

This does not work for the 'drone' user (but it does work for users with r/w access to 'parent'):

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //server.domain.org/SHARE/parent/child /mount_folder -o sec=ntlm,username=drone,password=secret,domain=domain,iocharset=utf8
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

It seems as though mount.cifs does permissions checking different from gvfs... is this configuable/fixable or a fundamental difference in the two programs?

Thanks!

Comment: same problem here. you did not find a solution in the meantime, didn't you?

Comment: Can't remember what I ended up doing... maybe just gave R/W access to the parent folder (which was not ideal). My samba foo is very weak, esp when it comes to mapping linux<->windows permissions.

Comment: I found my problem. I tried to mount a share which was nested inside another share (\\share_a\share_b). Decoupling this to get the real share_b address allowed me to mount share_b. I found the real share address when i mounted it in windows as a drive, selected a file/folder of that share, right click and opened properties. In the tab "DFS" the real address was hidden